# Cart added products are not displayed in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, products, ce-1.7.0.2, cart-items

if a user add a product to cart, the cart means 1 Item in cart, if i go to the cart, there are no products displayed.

A user can order, the added products are in the order and at paypal... The only problem is, that they didn't displayed in the cart.

In the past there was no error. I tried to uninstall all plugins, but the error was still the same.

Maybe the Shop URL might help: www.gartenmoebelgigant.de (CE 1.7.0.2)

Thanks for your help.

*Edit*

The Object is filled, because the total and subtotal is filled normal... Also the Button 1 Item in cart is correct... Only the table with cart details is not filled... There might be an error in it...

Tried already to change the template...didn't changed something... :-(

Thanks for your help

The problem might be here:

```
$this->getItemHtml($_item);
```

Comment: Could you list the (relevant) plugins/extensions that you are using?

Comment: What shows in the error log when you add to cart? Is there an error log? Can you chmod 777 [magento]/var so that the web server has write permissions?

Comment: Have already tried to uninstall all plugins, nothing changed...
There is nothing in the error log... The problem might be at the creation of the table with items in cart... but don't know where i can check...already tried to debug, but the object is to big

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some interface block doesn't refresh as I see subtotals update.

Have you tried turning off all cache and testing again?

Comment: Yes, tried to turning of the cache, nothing changed...
The object is filled, the subtotals and total is filled quite well. The only problem is the table where the items are displayed... i tried to debug already, but the object is very large...

Comment: Try to check if it is theme, extension or core related. If it happens also with the default theme - you should dig deeper. But if it is only with your current theme, then look there.

Comment: I already tried to use default theme, it might be a core problem, but i don't know where i can start to debug. Where are the core data for the creation of cart table?

if i debug, the shop breaks down, because the object is to big.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are doing when you say "if i debug". My experience is with CE 1.9+ but debugging principles are the same for all software: 1. Find the block/code which breaks. 2. Find the code which calls it. 3. Continue up the chain until you find "the missing semicolon" :)